# Colleagues laughing at my reply

Tags: india, meetings

About me : I am reserved person and I do not talk much. I have a good rapport with my team mates and my team lead. The project on which I work has 30-40 employess divided into 4-5 teams.

This incident happened during a project meeting. There were a few questions being asked about the project and employees answered as per their knowledge. There was one question to which I answered and no one else could. The moment I answered, everyone burst into a loud laughter. Though my manager acknowledged that it was the right answer, no one gave a damn about it. There was still a smile on their faces.

I was very much upset about this incident. I thought that may be they weren't expecting **me** to answer anything at all and so the mockery? I have no idea why they did at all but I wanted them or my manger to know that I was hurt by their reaction. How should I talk to my manager about it?

Comment: Before you talk to anyone, why did this upset you? Based on what you described it seems more likely someone told a joke and everyone laughed at the same time that you answered. I wasn't there, and I'm not really a sensitive person, but I don't really see anyway for your answer and the laughter to be connected.

Comment: @SaggingRufus No. There was no joke being told. It was a Q&A session, and it was going in a flow.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Everyone laughed the moment I answered it. And when the manager said that it was the right answer, everyone calmed down but still there were a few smiling faces. I interpreted this as mockery. Could this be interpreted in any other way?

Comment: @user75512 Im not saying that is what happened I said its more likely. Like I said, I wasn't there, but I can't possibly connect you answering a question (correctly) to them laughing with nothing else in between.

Comment: @SaggingRufus But, there was nothing else in between. Nothing at all.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Should I bring it to the notice of my manager that I was upset with this behavior? Or should I leave it?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If I were in his place, may be I would think that this is a trivial matter and brush it off? So, bringing up this issue would make no sense?

Comment: If you're new to the team, maybe your response inadvertently triggered some kind of in-joke, although in that case I would expect one of your colleagues to take you aside afterwards, apologize and explain. (In fact, it would have been nice if anyone had done so regardless of their reason for laughing.)

Answer (score 3):

As I have expressed in the comments, I can't really see the connection between you answering a question and everyone bursting out laughing BUT I can still answer you question.

If you are hurt by this and want to speak with your manager about it, then by all means do that. Before you do, please consider the following:

- Why did this upset you?
- Are you sure they were mocking you (how could you tell)?
- Are you prepared for the potential fall out?

If you bring this up with your manager, they will almost certainly want to know why you are upset and how it happened. If you expect this behaviour to change, your manager will then have to talk to the staff about the incident. Unfortunately, there isn't really anyway to bring this up anonymously because they laughed as you answered so they will know where the complaint came from. This could result in (depending on the maturity of your colleague) them doing it more often.

Personally, I would try to let it go and see if it continues. If the problem persists then bring it to the manager. If this was just a one time event, I would say I am probably right and they were not laughing at you. If it continues, you were right.

As for how to bring it up, ask for a meeting and tell your manager exactly what you told us:

> I was very much upset about this incident. I thought that may be they
>   weren't expecting me to answer anything at all and so they mocked me. I
>   have no idea why they did it.